# Faunadb: Create doc to a collection from a child database

Tags: node.js, faunadb

Need help. My code just runs to an error. It says: `Cannot write a scoped ref.`

Maybe it has to do with:

```js
q.Collection("Projects", q.Database("Apps"))
```

Here's my code:

```js
let data = {
  project: {
    id: 9273727,
    name: "test",
    author: "Matthieu"
  },
  content: []
}
client.query(q.Create(q.Collection("Projects", q.Database("Apps")), {data}))
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is correct. You can't do writes with scoped refs. Only read. You have to initiate your client with a secret that belongs to the database you want to write in. If you have a admin key you can create a *scoped* secret. Format it like so `{{serverKey}}:{{dbName}}:{{role}}`. Role could be `admin` or any other role.